# Why is the parent Div getting linked?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a Div inside of another. The child Div is a link starts a javascript animation (by animating the css properties) and the reason why I put in a wrapper is because I wanted to have the child be centred and float. So the child Div does the centering and the parent does the float. The reason is because you can't do `margin:0 auto;` with a `float:` property.

Now my problem is that when I put a link around the child Div, the parent Div gets linked too! It's really baffling me at the moment. This happens in Chrome and Firefox but strangely enough it does no happen in IE! Does anybody know what's wrong?

The parent is `#eastereggwrapper` and the child is `#eastereggbutton`. Here are the code snippets, my HTML:

```
<div id="eastereggwrapper">
  <a href="" class="secret" >
    <div id="eastereggbutton" >
      Don't Click Me
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
#eastereggwrapper {
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}

#eastereggbutton {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:10%; 
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    color: black;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
```

P.S. The secret class is not defined, it's used for the Javascript code.

Comment: What does "getting linked" mean? Show a jsfiddle where this happens please, with the same doctype as in your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of two things:

1. Place the `<a>` inside of the second div
2. Replace the child div with the `<a>` tag:

**HTML**

```
<div id="eastereggwrapper">
  <a href="" class="secret" id="eastereggbutton">
      Don't Click Me
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#eastereggbutton {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:10%; 
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    color: black;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Wow the second solution worked! Thanks, really weird why it does though :o

Comment: I would guess it's because the `<a>` tag, being inherently a `display: inline` element, tries to take up all the space it can instead of confining itself to the size of its child elements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to remember that!

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
#eastereggwrapper > a {
    width:10%;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

to your CSS and remove

```
margin:0 auto;
width:10%;
```

from the properties of #eastereggbutton

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and it works too! But unfortunately I already used the solution albertxing had provided. I wish I can accept both answers! :(